# aws resourcegroupstaggingapi retrieving resource that doesn't exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, tagging

I am using the resourcegroupstaggingapi to return a list of resources so that I can check for non-compliancy (ie resources without appropriate tagging).

On the email that gets created daily, I keep seeing an RDS cluster that has been deleted (via console) for over a week now.

When I run "aws rds describe-db-cluster", I get an empty response (as expected) however if I run "aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --resource-type-filters rds", it returns the cluster that I have deleted along with its tags.

Is this a bug or does the resourcegroupstaggingapi somehow return all resources regarding of status?

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 0):

Could you please double check your commands. The following:

```
aws rds describe-db-cluster
```

is **only for Aurora** and it will not list regular RDS databases. To **list regular RDS databases**, along with aurora ones, you have to use:

```
aws rds describe-db-instances
```

So maybe you are expecting regular databases to be deleted, but since you are using command only for Aurora, you think that there are no regular RDS instances? Similarly, you resource groups have been created for RDS instances, or DB clusters (Aurora)?

Comment: Thanks for the response Marcin.
I know that we currently only spin up Aurora hence only checking the former but have just tested with describe-db-instances and get the following returned....

{
    "DBInstances": []
}

Comment: @user1495536 The RDS and resource groups are regional. Are you sure you are using same regions when checking them and account?

Comment: Thought you may have been onto something there but unfortunately no.... cluster is in "arn:aws:rds:ap-southeast-2" which is correct.